# How to wait to another bundle?

Tags: java, osgi

I am developing an OSGi application which is composed by several bundles. All of them depend on the EventAdmin one. However, one specific plug-in has to start up a scheduled task as soon as the bundled is started (i.e. in the start method of the activator). The problem is that the event admin service is not still registered and I should wait for the deployment of this. I would not like to do this through the config properties file, therefore, is there any operation to do this without the properties file of Felix?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no start ordering in OSGi ... get over it ... Though there are mechanisms to influence the initial start ordering, the problem is that any bundle can stop at any time. So the ONLY solution is to actually handle your dependency on Event Admin.

With Declarative Services (DS), this is actually very little work. Also, please forget bundle activators, they are bundle singletons and are thus a bad idea. So in DS you would do the following (using the annotations):

```
@Component(immediate=true)
public class MyTask extends Thread {
    EventAdmin ea;


    public void run() {
        while ( !isInterrupted()) {
           // do something
           ea.postEvent(...);
        }
    }

    @Activate   void activate()                      { this.start();}
    @Deactivate void deactivate()                    { this.interrupt(); }
    @Reference  void setEventAdmin(EventAdmin ea)    { this.ea = ea;}
}
```

There are rare cases you should not use DS and are stuck with Bundle-Activators, but they are rare and should become rarer. If you're stuck with such a really bad case, then you can also create a service tracker in the Bundle Activator start method and track Event Admin services. Once you get one, you create a thread to run your code. When the service disappears you interrupt the thread. However, this is a much more complex solution.

There are also other service dependency manager but I strongly recommend Declarative Services with their annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [iPOJO](http://felix.apache.org/site/apache-felix-ipojo.html) for this. It is designed to be used in felix & karaf.  This library understands the lifecycle and dependencies of components and you will be notified via @Validate and @Invalidate methods when a components dependencies are available or one or more goes away.

It also support @Bind and @Unbind when an implementation of a service (an interface) appears or disappears.  This make subscriptions much simpler.

You have a listener to a service and this component @Provides an interface to be called.  The central event register will then be called on its @Bind method when such a component appears and @Unbind when it goes away for any reason.

I suspect iPOJO should do all the dependency management and binding you need.